# Relation that is transitive, symmetric but not antisymmetric nor reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given the following requirements:

> "R is transitive and symmetric but not antisymmetric nor reflexive"

I have found the following relation R on A, where **A = {1, 2, 3}**

**R = {(1,2), (2,1), (1,1)}**

Now from my understanding, this is transitive because:
$$(1,1)\in R\mbox{ and }(1,2)\in R,\mbox{ then }(1,2)\in R,$$
$$(1,2)\in R\mbox{ and }(2,2)\in R,\mbox{ then }(1,2)\in R.$$

It is also symmetric because for any $(a,b)$ there is also $(b,a)$.

It isn't antisymmetric because we have $(1,2)\ and \ (2,1)\ and \ 2 \neq 1$

And finally, it's not reflexive because $3$ is not related to it's self.

Now on my answer sheet it provides the following answer (it gives three, this was the closest to what I got)

**R = {(1,1), (2,2), (1,2), (2,1)}**

Where is the flaw in my logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By transitivity, given $(2,1) \in R$ and $(1,2) \in R$, you should also have $(2,2) \in R$. Given that you do not, your $R$ is not transitive.